# How can I use the payable function to transfer fixed ether in a transaction?

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, payable, transfer

```
contract MyContract {
    
    address payable[] recipients;
 
    function sendEther(address payable recipient) external payable {
        recipient.transfer(1 ether);
    }
}
```

Error- transact to MyContract.sendEther errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.

Answer (score 1):

Contract cannot take ethers from wallet address and transfer it, you need to pass the amount you wish to transfer as **VALUE**. Then your code should look like this:

```
function sendEther(address payable recipient) public payable {
    recipient.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

Then if you want to transfer only exact one ether you can have the following condition in your logic right above the ether transfer:

```
function sendEther(address payable recipient) public payable {
    require(msg.value == 1 ether, 'Only 1 ether allowed to be transfered.');
    recipient.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

Comment: thanks, can you please tell me how i can send ether to smart contract from an account

Comment: That's a different question from the current one, make a new question on this forum so others can join the discussion.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98565/how-to-send-a-fixed-amount-of-ether-to-a-smart-contract-from-an-account -- created